# Change result by function - python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I need to generate random number with 4 various literature,
so i wrote this program:

```
import random
def rand():
    i=0
    n=""
    while i<4:
        a = str(random.randint(0,9))
        if a not in n:
            n +=a
            i+=1
    return n
print (rand)
```

The content of the function is correct, but the function cause to strange result :

```
<function rand at 0x000001E057349D08>
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Not answering the question, but an alternative approach. Your whole function body could look like this: `return ''.join(random.sample('0123456789', 4))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the reference to the function itself instead of invoking it. To invoke it, you need to follow it with parenthesis (`()`):

```
print (rand())
# Here ----^
```